# Enviar lista de objetos para View, pela ViewBag Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Gostaria de obter uns dados:
Classe:

```
 public class Produto
    {
        public Produto()
        {
            this.Categoria = new HashSet<Categoria>().ToList();
        }

        #region Atributos
        [Key]
        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="o nome deve ser preenchido")]
        public string NomeDoProduto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "o codigo deve ser preenchido")]
        public string CodProduto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="o preço deve ser preenchido")]
        public decimal PrecoDeAtacado { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "o preço deve ser preenchido")]
        public decimal PrecoDeVarejo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1200)]
        public string Informacoes { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1200)]
        public string Decricao { get; set; }
        public bool? Disponibilidade { get; set; }
        public int Quatidade { get; set; }


        #endregion

        #region Chaves Estrangeiras
        public int CorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Cor Cor { get; set; }
        public int TamanhoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tamanho Tamanho { get; set; }
        public int ImagemId { get; set; }
        public virtual Imagem Imagem { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Comentario> Comentario { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

O produto tem Cor, e Tamanho.
Esse produto tem o `cód 123`
eu tenho mais produtos com o `cod 123`
Por exemplo:

```
Produto: Sapato Mocacin - Id: 1 - Cod: 123 - Tamanho: 39 - Cor: Preto
Produto: Sapato Mocacin - Id: 2 - Cod: 123 - Tamanho: 40 - Cor: Preto
Produto: Sapato Mocacin - Id: 3 - Cod: 123 - Tamanho: 39- Cor: Marrom
```

Na minha index, estou mostrando apenas 1 produto do tipo

```
Sapato Mocacin que tem o cod= 123
```

Na minha View detalhes mostro os detalhes do produto, do qual o usuario clicou,
gostaria saber como eu faço para mostrar os tamanhos e cores, do produto que tenha o `cod 123`
Quero fazer uma consulta, jogar em uma viewbag, e na view detalhesm criar um dropDownList para as opções dessa view bag, seja a da cor ou do tamanho.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Produto produto = db.ProdutoDb.Find(id);
            if (produto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }


            var geral = db.ProdutoDb.Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto);


            return View(produto);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulta a lista do seu banco de dados:

```
public List<Produto> ListaProduto()
{

    var listaProduto  = new List<Produto>();
    var objLista = context.TB_Produto.ToList();
    foreach (var item in objLista)
    {
        var produto = new Produto();
        produto.ProdutoId = item.ProdutoId;
        produto.NomeDoProduto = item.CodProduto + "-" + item.Tamanho + "-" + item.Cor;
        listaProduto.Add(produto);
    }  
    Return listaProduto 
}
```

No `controller` você pode fazer assim:

```
var listaProdutos = new ListaDeProdutos();
ViewBag.ddlProdutos = new SelectList(listaProdutos, "ProdutoId", "NomeDoProduto");
```

Na `view` você pode fazer assim:

```
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            <label for="ddlProdutos ">Selecione o Produto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlProdutos", string.Empty)
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

espero que te ajude!

Comment: Acredito que ele não queira mostrar o nome do produto com todas essas informações. Pra quem está usando o sistema não faz muito sentido ver o Id e Código desse exemplo. Mas provavelmente ele poderia tirar exemplo uteis da resposta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode selecionar as Cores e os Tamanhos a partir da sua `var geral`. Dessa forma:

```
var geral = db.ProdutoDb.Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto);

        ViewBag.TodasCores = 
            geral.Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto)
            .Select(s => s.Cor).Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.CorId.ToString(),
                Text = s.Descricao
            });

        ViewBag.TodosTamanhos = 
            geral.Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto)
            .Select(s => s.Tamanho).Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                Text = s.Descricao.ToString()
            });
```

Na sua View faça assim pra criar os DropDowns com as opções:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Cores", ViewBag.TodasCores as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("Tamanhos", ViewBag.TodosTamanhos as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Não costumo deixar minhas listas de `DropDowns` em `ViewBags`, costumo ter todos meus campos nas minhas `ViewModels`, mas no seu cenário e com `ViewBags`, conforme pediu, essa seria uma das formas de fazer.